# NLA Editor: select specific NLA track in python

Tags: python, nla-editor

Is there an easy way to select a specific NLA Track with a python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set the [`NLATrack.select`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.NlaTrack.html?k#bpy.types.NlaTrack.select) property to true.**

Sample script, selects all tracks, on context object, which have a name beginning with "Nla" The zeroth position track is set to active.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context 

ob = context.object
ad = ob.animation_data
if ad:
    for i, track in enumerate(ad.nla_tracks):
        # select all whose name starts with "Nla"
        track.select = track.name.startswith("Nla")
        # make active track if in pos 0
        if track.select and not i:
            ad.nla_tracks.active = track
```

Comment: It gives me an error in the console "AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "active" from "NlaTrack" is read-only" regarding line 11. The whole reason I'm doing this is to separate different NLA tracks into separate objects, if you know an easier way than duplicating, removing animations, then re-adding, please let me know.

Comment: Whoops, fixed it.